# MySQL JDBC driver getGeneratedKeys returning trigger-generated primary key values

Tags: mysql, jdbc, triggers, mysql-connector, connector-j

In MySQL, I'm using a before-insert trigger to create a value for a primary key column instead of using an `auto_increment` column (since my logic is more complex).

Is it possible for the MySQL JDBC driver (Connector/J) `Statement#getGeneratedKeys()` to return the value of the trigger-generated primary key values?

So far I've only seen it returning `auto_increment` values.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this in MySQL Connector/J.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I expected that to be the case.  Too bad...